Combine Slope and Aspect of a DEM for suitiable PV-Powerplants
I want to get areas for PV-Powerplants via QGIS.
I used the solution under Filter for south pointing areas from a DEM for extraction of the areas which are not facing north (60-300°).
But I need further information about the areas. Since an area can be minimal inclined lets say 0,1 ° to the north these areas will not be included, in reality they would be basically flat and therefore suitable for PV-parks.
How do I get the flat areas (no slope) and the minmal inclined areas up to 1° out of the DEM ?

The procedure is the same as in the answer you reference above, you just need to calculate the "slope" raster out of the DEM and reclassify values <= 1° to  1 and all others to 0.
